# Programmatic generation of Datomic queries

Tags: macros, clojure, datomic

#### Application

I'd like to programattically generate queries of the following form.

```
(q '[:find ?id ?val1 ?val2 ?val3 ?val4 ...
     :where [?x :id ?id] 
            [?x :attr1 ?val1]
            [?x :attr2 ?val2]
            [?x :attr3 ?val3]
            [?x :attr4 ?val4]
            ....]
     (db conn))
```

These are fairly standard queries to collect a predefined set of attributes.

#### Current Solution

The best I can do is to use `:in` as follows

```
(q '[:find ?id ?val
     :in  $ [?attr ...]
     :where [?x :id ?id] 
            [?x ?attr ?val]]
     (db conn) [:attr1 :attr2 :attr3 :attr4])
```

But this gives me a set of `n` facts for each entity.  Really I want to receive a set of vectors of length `n+1` where `n` is the number of specified attributes.  I also want the order of elements to reflect the order of the attributes as they are given.

#### Programmatic Generation

Because Datomic queries are data structures I should be able to programmatically generate them.  I find this difficult for a couple reasons, both of which stem from my unfamiliarity with macros

1. How can I create terms like `?val1`.  Can I map `?` onto a bunch of generated strings?

   `(map ? value-strings)`
2. The leading `'` scares me.  Doesn't this stop my automated code from running until after  elements like `?x` are dealt with?

Or, is there a more idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**...

as @TomJack writes, Datomic supports an alternate map-based syntax which will make your query easier.

```
(let [attributes [:name :height :weight :age]
      valnames (map #(symbol (str "?" (name %))) attributes)
      x-terms (map #(vector '?x %1 %2) attributes valnames)
      query {:find valnames
             :where (cons ['?x :id '?id] x-terms)}]
  (q query (db conn)))
```

Comment: syntax-quote is neither necessary nor helpful here. The query itself (without `q`, `(db conn)`) can be built up as a map and then just passed to datomic.api/q — see http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#sec-3-2